# How to start the new div from the last element?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How can I align the `and 9 others` in continuation with `<a>`.
As it is a 'div' it is starting from the next line.

I need to add a tooltip that shows rest of the users. And It should be in continuation with the last names of the users.

Expected :

[image: Expected]

Actual :

[image: Actual]

CSS:
[image: CSS]

Code:

```
return (
    <div>
      {allUsers > 0 
        ? (<div>
            {
              displayNames.map((user, index) => {
                return (
                  <a
                    key={user.id}
                  >
                    {name}
                  </a>
                );
              })
            }
            {
              users.length > 0
                && (
                  <TooltipLabel
                    text={tooltipTextWrapper('TODO')}
                    html={true}
                    position={'bottom'}
                    class="common-tooltip-setting"
                  >
                    {` and ${users.length} others`}
                  </TooltipLabel>
                )
            }
          </div>)
        : '-'
      }
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe creating a runnable snippet is better than a screenshot of code.

Comment: I don't know how this will effect your tooltip styling but you could: a) style the `tooltip-parent` as `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`, b) use spans instead of divs, c) look at using `display: flex;` on the div surrounding the a tags.

Comment: are you display the elements from an array?

Comment: Yes. It is showing the users from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `div.common-tooltip-setting`, add style `display: inline-block`:

```
<a .. />
<a .. />
<a .. />
<div class="common-tooltip-setting" style="display:inline-block;" ...>
  <div class="rail-text-title">and 9 others</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `div` is a block level element it will behave like it's having a line break before and after it. You could use a `span` element instead which is an inline element or you could use css `display: inline` to make the div an inline element.